# Deleting Thumb Cache in Windows 7 folder

Tags: windows-7, cache

Is it safe to delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\ThumbCacheToDelete` ?

And if so how do I do it ? It keeps telling me that it's used by other program in Explorer but not which ones.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Answers can be a solution!

Turn off thumb caching, then turn it back on

http://www.technoleros.com/turn-off-caching-of-windows-7-thumbnails-in-hidden-thumbs-db-files/

Not all versions of Vista-Windows 7 have Group Policy Editor though.

Another trick is to open task manager and an elevated (administrator) command prompt, leave both open, on the process tab, kill explorer.exe, use the command prompt to delete the files, then use task manager and do a File >New Task >type in explorer.exe to load you desktop again.

This article shows how to do it at boot, but just use the method above to do it without rebooting. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/55728-file-delete-command-prompt.html

If there is a permissions error when trying to delete, you may have to take ownership of the files first. For ownership refer http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-system-file-in-windows-vista/

Comment: I tried this and it partially solved my problem.  I had to remind myself how to open the elevated Cmd prompt, move around in the Cmd window and delete files.  But I followed your procedure (the "above method") and it helped me get my pdf previews back.  Now I just need to get my MS Word previews back....  Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the thumbnail cache from Disk Cleanup.  Windows doesn't let you delete it normally because it is indeed open for frequent reading and writing.  Please know that Windows does regenerate these over time.  If you don't want to see icon previews at all, you can go to 'Folder and search options' and check 'Always show items, never thumbnails'.